# onClick event to change className in mapped array with Hooks

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create an answer sheet, sometimes referred to as a "Bubble sheet", where the user clicks on "A,B,C, or D" and bubble changes from "light mode to dark mode" as when physically happens penciling in the answer.  (Using Tailwind.css)

I'm having a problem with 1) getting only one answer to change state (they all change) and 2) only being able to select one of the answers per question (A,B,C, OR D).   Any help would be appreciated as I'm close but stumped before the finish line (so to speak).

I'm passing in props.start from the parent component and repeating component to build answer sheets in increments of 25.  You could easily not pass any props and replace "props.start" with 1 to test this out.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Bubbles = (props) => {
  const [cName, setCname] = useState(
    'rounded-full px-2 mx-1 border border-red-600 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white'
  );

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const answer = event.target.id;
    setCname(
      'rounded-full px-2 mx-1 border border-red-600 bg-gray-700 text-white'
    );
    console.log(answer);
  };

  const NumberedArray = Array.from(Array(25), (_, i) => i + props.start);

  return (
    <div className='flex flex-wrap flex-col mx-3 overflow-hidden rounded'>
      {NumberedArray.map((number, index) => (
        <div
          className='flex h-10 w-full items-center justify-center bg-gray-100'
          key={index}
        >
          {number}
          <div id='A' className={cName} onClick={handleClick}>
            A
          </div>
          <div id='B' className={cName} onClick={handleClick}>
            B
          </div>
          <div id='C' className={cName} onClick={handleClick}>
            C
          </div>
          <div id='D' className={cName} onClick={handleClick}>
            D
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Bubbles;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're amazing and thank you SO much for the help, it's for people prepping for the Bar Exam so they don't have to write in their expensive prep materials and will be able to resell them (unmarked) .

Comment: what does props.start equals so i can reproduce this on codesandbox

Comment: You can use 1, when I repeat the component it looks like this :

          Bubbles start={1}

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement this.

set the default state `const [visibleOption,setVisible] = useState('')` , `const [selctedIndex,setSelctedIndex] = useState('')` and In **handleClick** you have to set the value that you passed and In return apply the ClassName as per Condition wise **className={`${cName} ${visibleOtion === 'A' && visibleClass}`}**.

```
    const [visibleOption,setVisible] = useState('')
    const [selctedIndex,setSelctedIndex] = useState('')

    const visibleClass = 'rounded-full px-2 mx-1 border border-red-600 bg-gray-700 text-white'

    const handleClick = (event,value,index) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const answer = event.target.id;
    setVisible(value)
    setSelctedIndex(index.toString())
    console.log(answer);
    };

     //In return written like this

      <div id='A' className={`${cName} ${visibleOtion === 'A' && selctedIndex === index.toString() && visibleClass}`} onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, 'A',index)}>
        A
      </div>
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: 1) So this SOLVES the "OR" problem as you can only select A,B,C, OR D.  Thank you!
2) However, when click on "A" the remaining 24 answers all change to A as well.  (using suggested return code).

Comment: @SteveFinley I have updated the code please take look.

Comment: Wish i can give answer but this would be the approach for the most part.

Comment: i recommend breaking your component up so you can avoid handleClick from changing all the values.

Comment: ALMOST THERE!  Only tweak left is that user is only able to answer 1/25 questions.   Selecting answers on another line (for example Question #2) clears the answers in Question 1.   It's WAY closer than I had it though. I'm humbled because this problem has stolen hours of my life.

Comment: With BARNOWL's advice, I extracted an ABCD component from Bubbles component and mapped ABCD in it's own component and mapped the 25 Questions in the Bubbles component and it works.   I wouldn't have been able to do it without the both of you and it means a lot to respond to strangers on Stack Overflow, so THANK YOU.

Comment: @Steve Finley No prob,  make sure you mark this as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Break this into 2 separate components.  1) ABCD and 2) Bubbles.   In ABCD, map over the answers array.  In bubbles, map over the 25 lines of answers.  That way you are selecting answers in the ABCD component and don't have the same issues I had.